# ATT wifi always shows, "secure-login.attwifi.com’s server IP address could not be found."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi-configuration

When I try to login to public wifi, I always get,

[image: chrome screen]

Which reads,

> This site can’t be reached
>   secure-login.attwifi.com’s server IP address could not be found.
>   Try:
>
> ```
>  Checking the connection
>  Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration
>  ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
> ```

I get this any time I try to connect to an att-commerical wifi spot, like the crap they likely traded for a happy meal to McDonalds,

[image: McDonalds Wifi]

Comment: I get the same message, doesn't look like it's a regular accessible site. The first google hit is https://my-attwifi.attwifi.com/ does that work instead? Why do you have to access that specific site anyway? McD's shows you the initial "get connected" page but then fails if you click connect? Their DHCP doesn't give a working nameserver?

Comment: @Xen2050 right on all accounts. the nameserver redirects to attwifi.attwifi.com on all http (non-https), and shits out when you hit connect becuase it can't reach the https site requested and my local cache doesn't have it (where as facebook just works)

Comment: ATT making the worst networks ever, forever.

Answer (score 2):

So if you're getting this error, it's likely because you have something like this set in your `/etc/resolve.conf`,

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search att.net
```

For whatever reasons, hitting connect on the [portal screen](http://login-1-sa-mcd.attwifi.com/guest/mcd-guest_3.php?venueConfigId=a030z00000llyvc-a1m0z000001gUm5&cmd=login&_browser=1) can't get you to the next step to resolve the process,

You may want to change the name servers to `8.8.8.8` so your `/etc/resolve.conf` looks like,

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```